# Backbone.js - FTScroller Cannot call method 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I used backboneJS to load a template and later render the template followed by initiate the FTScroller by requireJS. I cannot find how to fixed and couldnt find any documents for using with Underscore template. Anyone can help?

```
require(["ftscroller"], function () {
  scroller = new FTScroller(skrol, {
     scrollbars: false,
     scrollingY: false
  });
});
```

is there anyone willing to help?

Comment: i define the _skrol_ already and i thought the same maybe the **FTScroller** expect element is ready on the page. I'm looking forward for the dynamic one.

Comment: is there other plugin for scroller item like ftscroller that can be used with requirejs?